# Import TikTok Videos At Once

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, web-scraping, python-import

I'm Working On Android App Similar to TikTok and I Was thinking to given an Option to Import all TikTok Videos Of an Users on Our Android Studio but I'm not able to do this On Android App.

How To Do This Without Getting Watermark?

Comment: Don't know answer your question. But found this website http://snapall.xyz/

Comment: I'm Looking to implement Codes on Android App to Scrape Tiktok videos of User by putting username and then all videos Will store in Our Android App With the User Who Imported. Sorry For My English.